# How do I repair terrazzo floors?

Tags: repair, flooring

I just bought an older house and it has terrazzo floors the whole way through.  The previous owner installed carpet using tack strips that were nailed to the floor, instead of using contact cement, so when the carpet and the tack strips were removed it left divots in the floor along the baseboards of every room.  Is there any way to repair this?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but probably something that you would call in a professional for.  Even assuming that you had epoxy resin based floors, you'd still have to match the existing colors and sizes of the terrazzo pieces, clean out the nail holes, refill them, and grind and polish so they're level with the rest of the floor.

EDIT: Found this [article](http://ncr.gsa.gov/HistoricPreservation/htmldoc/43rmtf.asp) that suggests that repairing an epoxy based floor might be easier than I thought.  I'd still get some professional advice first though.

Answer (score 1):

DEFINITELY get professional advice here. If there are many floors of this type in your area, there will also be someone who specializes in repairing them. Start asking around. Call a few people who can create this type of floor. Somebody will know who does repair work on them. If you do find someone who claims to be able to repair them, get references and talk to the references.

An alternative to a repair might be to consider some sort of baseboard molding around the perimeter of your floors, to hide the divots. Of course, there may be spots in doorways where that is more difficult to do.